# How is unrolled linked list better than linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, overhead

I was studying the book "Data Structure and algorithms made easy" and but I got confused while learning "Comparing Linked Lists and Unrolled Linked list"...

what is overhead?
Why he is only stating 8 bytes of overhead for 100 elements array?

[image: Para from book]

Comment: **Each** node is going to take 8 bytes (two 4-bytes pointers), not 8 bytes for 100 elements.

Comment: Look for the difference between listnode and listblock... what do they refer to?

Comment: I think there are errors in the book. The `struct LinkedBlock` seems wrong. Have you checked for updates/later versions of the book?

Comment: @4386427 This is the latest version of the book

Comment: The consensus seems to be that your book leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the book contains a serious error in the definition of `struct LinkedBlock`. Let's get back to that later and start with:

> what is overhead?

The `struct ListNode` is designed for storing **one integer** but besides the integer each node has two pointers. So for each node you'll need to allocate 1 integer + 2 pointers. Let's assume 4 byte integer and 4 byte pointer. So each node will require 4 + 2x4 = 12 bytes. So in order to store 1 item of your real data (aka 1 integer) you need to allocate 12 bytes. You have wasted 8 bytes on pointers. These 8 "wasted" bytes are called overhead. They are used for bookkeeping only - not for data.

But it get worse than that... When allocating dynamic memory (which you normally do when using linked list) there are some additional overhead. The allocator may need a little extra memory for every `malloc` to store information about the `malloc`. Another issue is that `malloc` ed memory may aligned to some fixed block size (e.g. 16 or 32 byte) so if you allocate 20 byte there is no way to use the remaining 12 bytes - they are wasted. This is what the book calls "allocation overhead". The "allocation overhead" is system dependent but the book assumes 8 extra overhead bytes from each `malloc`.

So now each `malloc` 'ed `struct ListNode` takes up:

4 bytes for the integer

8 bytes for 2 pointers

8 bytes for allocation overhead

A total of 20 bytes where 4 bytes is for your data and 16 bytes are overhead. So for each integer you need to store, you'll need 20 bytes. And if you want to store 1000 integers, you end up wasting 16kb on overhead in order to store 4kb of data.

Now back to the `struct LinkedBlock`. In the book it looks like this:

```
struct LinkedBlock {
    struct LinkedBlock *next;
    struct LinkedNode *head;
    int nodeCount;
};
```

I'm pretty sure there is a mistake in the book and that it should look like this instead:

```
struct LinkedBlock {
    struct LinkedBlock *next;
    int *dataArray;
    int nodeCount;
};
```

The way to use this is something like:

```
struct LinkedBlock pNode = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedBlock));
pNode->dataArray = malloc( 100 * sizeof(int) );
```

The first `malloc` requires 4 + 4 + 4 + 8 = 20 bytes. (pointer, pointer, int, allocation overhead)

The second `malloc` requires 4 * 100 + 8 = 408 bytes. (100 int, allocation overhead)

So a total of 428 bytes.

However, since the `malloc`'ed data can hold 100 integers (corresponding to 400 bytes), your overhead is only 28 bytes. In other words - in average you use 4.28 bytes for each integer. Compare that to the first method that required 20 bytes for each integer.

> Why he is only stating 8 bytes of overhead for 100 elements array?

That was because the array was allocated in a single call and each `malloc` call is assumed to have 8 bytes allocation overhead.

Comment: I think it's confusing that allocation overhead is even a part of the discussion. For all we know all the data and the nodes could be statically allocated up front. It wouldn't moot the point that "block lists" save space and it would be a heck-of-a-lot less confusing. The author might mention structure padding as well and muddle the discussion further.

Comment: @Aksel I kind of agree. The author could easily prove the point without making things more complex by including "allocation overhead". I have not read that book and the page posted here makes me think that it's **not** worth to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Overhead is all the stuff that is not part of the data that you want to store. Like the pointers to the next and previous element.

The block list is a list of arrays. Each array contains a number of elements. In principle your entire list could consist of a single block node with an array of all your elements. So less overhead.

It's a bit confusing that head in LinkedBlock points to a ListNode - it should point to whatever the data is (without the prev and next pointers).

Comment: I've never heard the term "unrolled" used with lists. That term is usually reserved for loops in my book. Anyone?

Comment: I haven't either.

Comment: Blimey. Unrolled lists.

Answer (score 1):

In normal linked list, 1 node have 1 element and 2 pointer (8 bytes), 2 pointer is overhead since it's not your data. In unrolled linked list, 1 node have 100 element and 2 pointer (8 bytes), hence 8 bytes overhead for 100 element.